# How to skip active record for existing project in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an existing Rails project which I created in API mode, using no DB. Upon trying to deploy to Heroku, I am getting lots of ActiveRecord related errors.

```
-----> Detecting rake tasks
 !
 !     Could not detect rake tasks
 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
 !     rake aborted!
 !     URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): ://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname
  ...
  ...
/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To replicate the `skip-active-record` setup in an existing project, follow the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19078854/8940624)

PLUS

REMOVE **config/environments/development.rb** -> `config.active_storage.service = :local`

REMOVE **config/environments/production.rb** -> `config.active_storage.service = :local`

REMOVE **config/environments/test.rb** -> `config.active_storage.service = :local`

REMOVE **bin/setup** ->  `puts "\n== Preparing database =="
  system! 'bin/rails db:prepare'`

DELETE **config/storage.yml**

REMOVE **test/test_helper.rb**  `# Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all`